# Post.count not working properly on search results page (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple Rails app which has an index page that shows 59 posts.

The problem is that if I search for something, Post.count continue to show me the original number of Posts on the index page - for example if I search for a post called 'Quilon', I get a search result showing just 1 post, but the Post.count still shows the original post number which is 59.

How do I fix this?

**INDEX.HTML.ERB CODE**

```
<%= Post.count %>
```

**SEARCH FUNCTION IN POSTS CONTROLLER**

```
def index
    @posts = Post.all
    if params[:search]
      @posts = @posts.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    if params[:zagat_status].present?
      @posts = @posts.zagat_status(params[:zagat_status]).order("created_at DESC")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try `<%= @posts.count %>`

Comment: I think you need to replace @posts.count

Comment: @posts.count worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `<%= @posts.count %>` instead of `<%= Post.count %>`. `<%= Post.count %>` returns `count` of ***all the records***. It is just same as

```
select count(*) from "posts"
```

so the conditions are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

In your index action you narrow down the posts using some conditions, so you should operate on `@posts` variable, not on the model `Post` itself.

Which means you want to use `@posts.count`.

Answer (score 1):

Use @posts.count instead of Post.count